# В чём состоит отличие между различными workflow?

Tags: git, контроль-версий, dvcs

Слышал о существовании большого количества *workflow* (процессов разработки) — *git flow*, *github flow*, *gitlab flow.*

В чём их сущность и чем они отличаются? Ведь ветвление происходит во всех трёх случаях.

Comment: Согласен, что дубликат. Но всё равно дважды плюс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, все *workflow* имеют много общего, поскольку предназначены для работы с одними и теми же инструментами (в данном случае с *git*-ом, распределённой системой контроля версий, обладающей возможностью лёгкого ветвления).

Однако у них имеются весьма существенные различия в том, *как* с этими ветками обращаться.

1. **[Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)**

   Есть две фиксированные ветви, «стабильный» *master* и «развивающийся» *develop*. При появлении необходимости внесения изменений в код происходит одно из двух:

   - от *develop* отпочковывается тематическая ветка, если это внесение функционала или подготовка к выпуску новой версии,
   - либо ветка отпочковывается прямо от *master*, если это исправление ошибки.

   После окончания работ тематическая ветвь вливается в её родителя, а в ряде случаев — и в *master*.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. **[GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/)**

   То же, что и Git Flow, но фиксированная ветка всего одна — *master*; всё остальное принадлежит тематическим ветвям. Тематические ветви, в свою очередь, создаются в *форках* — клонированных копиях репозитория. То есть центральный репозиторий тематических веток не содержит. В том числе и после слияния, так как метки веток при этом снимаются и их головы становятся анонимными.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. **[GitLab Flow](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/)**

   Как и в GitHub Flow, фиксированная ветка всего одна — *master*; всё остальное принадлежит тематическим ветвям. Однако, если в том случае релизы размещались в коммитах *master-a*, то здесь для каждого релиза создаётся своя, отдельная ветка. Причём никакого слияния этих веток с родителем не производится. Если ветка отпочковалась, значит она будет жить своей жизнью, получая исправления ошибок в виде отдельных коммитов (возможно, портированных из головы мастера с учётом накопившейся разницы в функционале между ветками).

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

<sup>Иллюстрации были взяты из [статьи «잘 밤에 쓸데없는 생각하기...»](https://ujuc.github.io/2015/12/16/git-flow-github-flow-gitlab-flow/). В корейском я не смыслю, но картинки красивые.</sup>

Comment: GitLab Flow - Вся разработка ведётся в ветке master - нет, они наоборот, советуют feature branches, это прямо сказано в статье по вашей ссылке. Просто не показано на картинке, потому что картинка относится только к управлению релизами

Comment: Therefore we propose the GitLab flow as clearly defined set of best practices. It combines feature driven development and *feature branches* with issue tracking. Т.е. GitLab Flow = Github Flow + release branches.

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо за замечание, исправил.