# Когда использовать commit, tag, branch, push в Git?

Tags: git

В каком случае что использовать? С репозиторием работает один человек, git используется для удобства. Фишки совместной работы не берем.

1) Commit, насколько я понимаю, нужен для фиксации последовательных изменений. Но для меня не понятно, когда его использовать. Хочу откатиться на предыдущие коммиты, последующие все равно остаются, получается бардак. Фактически полезен он только для отката последних действий. Откатываться назад вглубь более, чем на один коммит - это уже беда. Если есть часть изменений, которую надо откатить, но сделаны и другие изменения, то эти другие утеряются. Верно? Какова польза коммита?

2) Branch, насколько я понимаю, нужен как раз в случае, если есть какие-то изменения, которые надо откатить, и те, которые не надо. Путем манипуляций с ветками я могу создавать нужную комбинацию того, что мне нужно оставить. Каковы основные случаи использования branch?

3) Как в общую концепцию вписываются теги? Какого их основное назначение?

4) Когда я должен использовать push? У меня все работает, я уверен, что это важная веха - сохраняю на сервер?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424882/git-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8/424887?s=3|0.0000#424887

Comment: 1. Обычно commit делают когда вы сделали какую то работу, после завершения которой код опять находится в работоспособном состоянии. можно откатить любой коммит с помощью git revert. 2. ветки полезны, когда вы делаете какую то крупную работу и в процессе этого вам иногда надо не доделав ее до конца быстро сделать что то совершенно другое. и выложить изменения стабильной версии +изменения по срочной работе, но не выкладывая на половину разломанный код образовавшийся из за незавершенной первой работы.

Comment: push в вашем случае нужен только для бекапа. А вообще, даже если выработаете один над каким то важным проектом, обычно у вас существует развернутый где то стабильный код, который в работе у пользователей и отдельно ваша отладочная версия. с помощью push/pull вы выкатываете на продакт те изменения, которые делали у себя отладке

Comment: Какого рода контент вы собираетесь хранить в git и как работали до этого?

Comment: Код для мобильных приложений и веб-сайтов. До этого - руками. Какие-то изменения - бекап, делаю изменения, если что-то не работает, то восстанавливаю бэкап, изменения удаляю. Гитом не пользовался по принципу "все пользутся и мне надо" или "ты плохой разработчик, если не знаешь гит". Инструменты использую именно в качестве инструментов. На данный момент осознал на одном из последних проектов, потребность в инструменте, который бы позволил облегчить работу. Пришлось интегрировать библиотеку с кучкой проблем, которые привели к созданию кучи папок с бэкапом проекта и в конце - путаница.

Comment: `Каковы основные случаи использования branch?` — это зависит исключительно от того, как у вас организована работа с репозиториями (по-английски *workflow*). Несколько примеров подобной организации с иллюстрациями приведены в ответе к вопросу «[В чём состоит отличие между различными workflow?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676514/208074)».

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разберемся по пунктам.

### Commit

---

`git commit` действительно нужен для фиксации изменений.

Давайте подумаем как решить Ваши проблемы:

> Хочу откатиться на предыдущие коммиты, последующие все равно остаются, получается бардак.

можно *сгладить*. Конкретно эту проблему можем решить коммандой [`git reset`](https://habr.com/post/203282/).

Выполнение `git reset` "приводит" состояние репозитория к указанному коммиту, при этом удаляя всех предыдущие коммиты. Например:

У нас есть репозиторий со следующим состоянием:

`C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4(HEAD)`.

Мы понимаем, что последние два коммита - полный бред, их нужно удалить, не оставляя их при этом в репозитории. Решение - `git reset`. После выполнения `git reset --hard C2` Получим следующий вид репозитория:

`C1 -- C2(HEAD)`

При этом мы потеряем все изменения в коммитах C3 & C4.

> Если есть часть изменений, которую надо откатить, но сделаны и другие изменения, то эти другие утеряются

Но что если нам нужно их сохранить, но убрать из репозитория? Решение - `git reset --soft C2`. Получим тот же вид репозитория:

`C1 -- C2(HEAD)`

Но, при этом у нас останутся наши изменения из C3 & C4 в индексе (в том виде, как будто бы вы их только что добавили командой `git add -A`)

---

Есть еще один вариант решения этой проблемы - `git revert`. Эта команда не удаляет изменения из git repository, а просто создает "отменяющий" коммит - после которого, в Вашем репозитории просто добавиться коммит с изменениями из указанного, в котором Вы можете сделать необходимые изменения. Например после применения комманды `git revert C2` репозиторий будет иметь следующий вид:

`C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4 -- RC2(HEAD)`

Вот Вам отличные, на мой взгляд ответы со stackoverflow, объяснующие работу с отменой изменений:

1. [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83)
2. [Откатить уже опубликованный коммит и опубликовать новый, не вызывая мержа у других](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429512/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3)

---

> Но для меня не понятно, когда его использовать.

Используйте `git commit` когда хотите зафиксировать какую-то законченую часть Ваших изменений.

Например, у Вас есть большая задача *А*, которую Вы можете (желательно) разбить на мелкий подзадачи (сделать декомпозицию задачи). В итоге получите:

```
A:
--A1
--A2
--A3
----A3.1
----A3.2
--A4
```

После выполнения каждой подзадачи - делаете *commit*, фиксируя изменения. В итоге, в случае, если Вы получите какую-то ошибку на определенном этапе - Вам будет легко откатиться на какой-либо этап.

([git commit message convention](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/))

Если большое количество коммитов в разрезе задачи Вас смущает - можете использовать [`git squash`](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/27-how-to-squash-commits-and-why-it-is-needed). Тогда после выполнения всей задачи - в основную рабочую ветку будет отправлен один большой коммит.

### Branch

---

> Branch, насколько я понимаю, нужен как раз в случае, если есть какие-то изменения, которые надо откатить, и те, которые не надо.

Вариантов использования веток масса, это - только один из них. Ниже я опишу еще один, который много где используют.

> Путем манипуляций с ветками я могу создавать нужную комбинацию того, что мне нужно оставить.

Можете, но *на мой взгляд* - это не самый удачный вариант.

> Каковы основные случаи использования branch?

Как я уже говорил выше - вариантов использований веток много. Вот один из них, который принят много где.

Пускай у нас есть репозиторий с ветками:

```
 MASTER:  C1 -- C2 -- C3(HEAD)
                      |                
 DEVELOP: C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4(HEAD)
```

Каждая новая задача (баг, новый функционал ака фича, не важно) - вы создаете новую ветку (принято делать это от максимально стабильной, рабочей ветки - master) `git checkout master; git checkout -b new_feature_branch`:

```
 MASTER:      C1 -- C2 -- C3(HEAD)
                          |                
 DEVELOP:     C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4(HEAD)
                          |
 NEW FEATURE: C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- FC4 -- FC5(HEAD)
```

, где *FC4-FC5* - коммиты в Вашей новой ветке.

После завершения работы над задачей - делаете `pull request` в **DEVELOP**:

```
 MASTER:      C1 -- C2 -- C3(HEAD)
                          |                
 DEVELOP:     C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4(HEAD) <---------|
                          |
 NEW FEATURE: C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- FC4 -- FC5(HEAD) --|
```

на котором тестируете Вашу работу, после чего делаете `pull request` **DEVELOP** в **MASTER**.

```
 MASTER:      C1 -- C2 -- C3(HEAD) <---------------|
                          |                
 DEVELOP:     C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4(HEAD) ----------|           
                          |
 NEW FEATURE: C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- FC4 -- FC5(HEAD)
```

Таким образом вы легко можете смотреть на историю изменений Вашего функционала и в случай чего - отменять изменения, сделанные в Вашей "фиче".

Более высокоуровневое решение этой работы - [*git flow*](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.ru_RU.html).

### Tags

---

> Как в общую концепцию вписываются теги?

Здесь не совсем понятно, что Вы подразумеваете под "общей концепцией", поэтому дать ответ на этот вопрос не смогу.

> Какого их основное назначение?

Они используются для фиксации каких-либо *важных* моментов в истории Вашего репозитория. С другой стороны, их часто используют для [версионирования](https://semver.org/lang/ru/).

### Push

---

> У меня все работает, я уверен, что это важная веха - сохраняю на сервер?

Не обязательно.

> Когда я должен использовать push?

Зависит от ситуации. Например, если Вы работаете с кем-то и ему понадобились Ваши изменения - `git push` - он уже у себя сделает `git pull` и получит Ваш код.

Или Вы работаете на другой машине, например, на работе, но хотите еще поработать позже дома - `git push`, а дома уже забираете свои изменения и работаете дальше.

Comment: Много говорить не буду. Звучит высокопарно, но пока есть такие люди, которые могут вот так ответить на вопрос и так соучастно реагировать, можно сказать, что эволюция есть и мы, как человечество, далеко пойдем. Спасибо за ответ, дорогого стоит. Перевариваю.

Comment: "После завершения работы над задачей - делаете pull request в DEVELOP:..." "на котором тестируете Вашу работу" <- вот тут я сломался. А как? Про всё классно написано, но pull request и вот эти слова "на котором тестируете Вашу работу" всё сломали в мозгу)

Comment: @Sima, да, тут возможно нужны пояснения. Я имел в виду ситуацию, когда вы разрабатываете условно веб-сайт и у вас есть несколько окружений (девовское, прод, релиз кандидат и т.п.). Ну и соответственно ветки связаны с этим окружением.